# How do I create a service dependency after registering that said service in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I resolved a previous issue through adding a service dependency when a package is installed. Since the dependency is created during the installation, it gets removed when switching from an older version of the package. The versions should be interchangeable without losing new dependencies,

I am looking to add the dependency after the service is registered during a version change, so I wondering how to do that in C++. These are resources I've found on how to add it in the terminal, but not in a C++ function:

[Adding Windows Service Dependency](https://serverfault.com/questions/24821/how-to-add-dependency-on-a-windows-service-after-the-service-is-installed)

[Service Dependencies - Registry](https://esxsi.com/2016/11/01/service-dependencies/)

I also want to make sure that the service dependency that exists isn't removed (RPCSS)

Answer (score 1):

Service dependencies can be specified either:

- when the service is first created, using the `lpDependencies` parameter of [`CreateService()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicew)
- after the service is created, using the `lpDependencies` parameter of [`ChangeServiceConfig()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-changeserviceconfigw)

Comment: Thank you! Since the service is created using CreateProcess() I am going to create a function that uses ChangeServiceConfig() to append the missing dependency.